# Given a path to a file assosiated with a github release how can I download it in c#

Tags: c#, .net, github, dotnet-httpclient

So when I make a release it triggers actions that build different projects in the solution. I want to be able to download a file that is added to the release via these actions. When I am logged in I can download the file using the following url: https://github.com/PhoeniqsTech/ForianSolution/releases/download/v0.0.1/Forian.BiotrackAgent-v0.0.0-test-win-x64.zip which I'm sure will result in a 404 for you since its a private repo.

I have tried to download this file using by personal access token with all rights given to it in the following ways but all I get is a 404 response.

#### Test 1

```
public async Task TestOne()
{
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue("AppName", "1.0"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", AccessToken);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(GithubZipfile);
    byte[] contents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(contents));
}
```

#### Test 2

```
public async Task TestTwo()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var credentials = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:", AccessToken);
    credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
    var contents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(GithubZipfile);
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(LocalFile, contents);
}
```

#### Test 3

```
public async Task TestThree()
{
    using HttpClient client = new();
    var credentials = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "UserName:{0}", AccessToken);
    credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
    var contents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(GithubZipfile);
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(LocalFile, contents);
}
```

#### Test 4

```
public async Task TestFour()
{
    using HttpClient client = new();
    var credentials = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "UserName:{0}", AccessToken);
    credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", credentials);
    var contents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(GithubZipfile);
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(LocalFile, contents);
}
```

Has anyone else figured out how to download release files from GitHub programmably in dotnet?

Comment: Were you able to download the zip from Postman for example?

Comment: @PeterCsala I didn't try. Also gave up on doing it. Does postman do anything differently then what I was doing with HttpClient?

Comment: I have seen  a lots of SO questions where the request was okay from Postman but failed with HttpClient. Postman has a built-in feature to generate code from request. It does support C# codegen as well.

Comment: @PeterCsala Ill try to set aside some time this or next week to  try it out.

Comment: @PeterCsala Looks like I was not using the correct endpoint to download the file. That endpoint seems to only support cookie based authentication and is only supposed to be used from a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot at this time download a file using that path outside of a browser. The "correct" way to download an asset is to first list the assets in a release:

Url: https://api.github.com/repos/PhoeniqsTech/ForianSolution/releases/tags/v0.0.3

Headers:

Authorization: Bearer {PersonalAccessToken}

Accept: application/vnd.github+json

This returns a result with all assets in a release. For each asset there is a url field that can be used to download the file. My example download request is configured as follows:

Url: https://api.github.com/repos/PhoeniqsTech/ForianSolution/releases/assets/78691863

Headers:

Authorization: Bearer {PersonalAccessToken}

Accept: application/octet-stream

Comment: @PeterCsala Its amazing how quickly you can solve an issue that you spent hours on after a long break from the problem lol.

Comment: It was not that long :) Thanks for sharing your findings.